How to evaluate Integral:$\int^1_0\ln\left({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx$
I need help to evaluate Integral:$$I=\int^1_0\ln\left({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx$$
Let $x=\sin(y)$.
$$\begin{align}I&=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos(y)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sin(y)}{1-\sin(y)}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\cos(y)}{1-\cos(y)}}\right)dy\\&=4\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \cos(y)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\cos(y)}{\sin(y)}}\right)dy\end{align}$$
I'm stuck on the solution here. Any help on how to evaluate this integral?
This integration is from the book Special Functions.
The answer is given in the book as equal to:$$I=8G-\frac{\pi^2}{2}$$where $G=\int_0^1 \frac{\sinh ^{-1} x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ is Catalan’s constant.

I suppose you intend $1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the denominator ("$-$" instead of "$+$")

else the argument of the second ln is $1$ and hence that ln evaluates to $0$, i.e. you'll integrate the $0$-function. But this won't match your given result. - But then again, what is "G" supposed to be?

What's up with the downvotes on answers? I don't see anything that warrants this.

Continue with the substitution $x=\sin t$
\begin{align}
&\int^1_0\ln{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{dx}\\
=& \ 4\int_0^{\pi/2}\tanh^{-1}(\sin t) \tanh^{-1}(\cos t)\ d(\sin t)\\
\overset{ibp}=&\  4 \int_0^{\pi/2}\tanh^{-1}(\sin t)dt
-4 \int_0^{\pi/2}\tan t\tanh^{-1}(\cos t)dt\\
=&\ 4\cdot (2G)- 4\cdot \frac{\pi^2}8=8G -\frac{\pi^2}2
\end{align}
where
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tanh^{-1}(\sin t)dt\overset{\sin t=\frac{1- s^2}{1+s^2}}=-2\int_0^1\frac {\ln s}{s^2+1}ds =2G
$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan t\tanh^{-1}(\cos t)dt\overset{s^2=\tan\frac t2}=\int_0^1\frac {\ln s}{s^2-1}ds=\frac{\pi^2}8
$$

\begin{align}J&=\int^1_0\ln\left({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx\\
&\overset{u=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}}=16\int_0^1\frac{u\ln\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)\ln u}{(1+u^2)^2}du\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-8\underbrace{\left[\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)\ln u}{1+u^2}\right]_0^1}_{=0}+8\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)}{u(1+u^2)}du}_{=J_1}-16\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{1-u^4}du}_{=J_2}\\
J_1&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)}{u}du}_{=J_{1,1}}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{u\ln\left(\frac{1-u}{1+u}\right)}{1+u^2}du}_{=J_{1,2}}\\
J_{1,1}&\overset{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{1-z^2}dz=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{1-z}dz-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{2z\ln z}{1-z^2}dz}_{w=z^2}\\
&=-2\zeta(2)+\frac12\zeta(2)=\boxed{-\frac32\zeta(2)}\\
J_{1,2}&\overset{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}=\int_0^1\frac{(1-z)\ln z}{(1+z)(1+z^2)}dz=\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{1+z}dz-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{z\ln z}{1+z}dz}_{w=z^2}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{1+z}dz-\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln w}{1+w}dw=\frac34\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{1+z}dz\\
&=\frac34\int_0^1\frac{\ln z}{1-z}dz-\frac34\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{2z\ln z}{1-z^2}dz}_{w=z^2}=-\frac34\zeta(2)+\frac38\zeta(2)=\boxed{-\frac38\zeta(2)}\\
&\boxed{J_1=J_{1,1}-J_{1,2}=-\frac{9}{8}\zeta(2)}\\
J_2&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{1-u}du-\frac14\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{2u\ln u}{1-u^2}du}_{z=u^2}+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{1+u^2}du\\
&=-\frac12\zeta(2)+\frac18\zeta(2)-\frac{\text{G}}2=\boxed{-\frac38\zeta(2)-\frac{\text{G}}2}\\
&\boxed{J=8J_1-16J_2=-3\zeta(2)+8\text{G}=8\text{G}-\frac{\pi^2}{2}}\\
\end{align}
NB:
I assume that,\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx&=-\zeta(2)\\
\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}

Using the same strategy as before:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= 4 \int_0^1 \operatorname{artanh}x \operatorname{arsech}x \, dx \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \int_x^1 \frac{\operatorname{artanh} x}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dx\, dy = 4 \int_0^1 \int_0^y \cdots \, dx\,dy \\
&= 4 \int_0^1 \frac{y \operatorname{artanh}y + \frac12 \log\left(1-y^2\right)}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy & \text{by parts} \\
&= 4 \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{artanh}y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy}_{2G} + 2 \int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(1-y^2\right)}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, dy \\
&= 8G + 4 \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log y}{1-y^2}}_{-\frac{\pi^2}8} & y\to\sqrt{1-y^2} \\
&= \boxed{8G - \frac{\pi^2}2}
\end{align*}$$
The first labeled integral is listed here. The second is well-known and may be evaluated by exploiting Taylor series, for instance.

\begin{align}
&\int^1_0\ln{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{dx}\\
\overset{IBP}=& \int^1_0\ln{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\;\mathrm d\bigg((1+x)\ln(1+x)+(1-x)\ln(1-x)\bigg)\\
=&2\int_0^1\bigg((1+x)\ln(1+x)+(1-x)\ln(1-x)\bigg)\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\;\mathrm dx\\
\overset{x\to\sin x}=&2\int_0^{\pi/2}\bigg(\frac{2\ln\cos(x)}{\sin x}+\ln(1+\sin x))-\ln(1-\sin x)\bigg)\;\mathrm dx\\
=&4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln\cos(x)}{\sin x}\;\mathrm dx+2\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x})\;\mathrm dx\\
=&-\frac{\pi^2}2-4\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\tan(\frac x2)dx\\
=&-\frac{\pi^2}2+8G.
\end{align}

Proceeding similar to this,
$$I=\int^1_0\ln\left({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx$$
As the bounds are from $0$ to $1$ , needless to say that this series stands for $|x|<1$,
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
A simple transformation taken from here
$$I=2\int^1_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx $$
$$I=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}\int_0^1x^{2n+1}\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)\,dx$$
Integrating by parts, we get
$$I=4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}=\frac{4^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}$$
Using the above result,
$$I=2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$
Using the below result,
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}=\frac{4G}{\sqrt{\pi}}-\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{\pi}}}$$
$$\boxed{\color{red}{\int^1_0\ln\left({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)\ln\left({\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)dx=8G-\frac{\pi^2}{2}}}$$

Partial fraction split,
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(2n+1)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(2n+2)\Gamma\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}G-\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{\pi}}}$$
$$\boxed{2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{(n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}+4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{(2n+1)^2\binom{2n}{n}}-4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}G-\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{\pi}}}$$
